# Баг с анимацией в хроме при использовании overflow:hidden

Tags: css, css-animation

```css
.border {
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid #cd2929;
  height: 6.25rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  width: 6.25rem;
}
.animate {
  background-color: #cd2929;
  width: 142%;
  height: 142%;
  left: -3.125rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.125rem;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  -webkit-animation: animate 5s forwards;
  animation: animate 5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 8.875rem);
  }
}
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 8.875rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Некорректно отображается анимация при ширине дочернего элемента более 100% или при `overflow:hidden` у родителя.

В хроме анимация останавливается посередине, а в firefox все нормально.
Интересно, почему? Как исправить?

Comment: интересный случай, уверен что это баг хрома. Я думаю стоит воспользоваться другим способом. Хотелось бы уточнить, а почему используется `rem` для ширины и высоты, это критично?

Comment: Нет, не критично. Попробую другой способ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Решение:

```css
.diamond {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #cd2929;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.diamond__fill {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25%;
  bottom: -25%;
  right: -25%;
  left: -25%;
  background-color: #cd2929;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(100%);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(100%);
  -webkit-animation: fill 5s forwards;
  animation: fill 5s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fill {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(100%);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(0);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(100%);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(0);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="diamond">
  <div class="diamond__fill"></div>
</div>
```

### Пояснение:

1. Что касается проблемы, то почти уверен, что это баг (не удачное сочетание анимирования `height` c `overflow` и `rotate`).
2. Выше представлен немного другой способ решения задачи через `translateY`.
3. Ромб может быть **любого размера**, размеры (`-25%`) вложенного элемента `diamond__fill` подобраны экспериментальным путем и занимают чуть большую площадь.